# Как сверстать такой блок при помощи html css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Подскажите как сверстать блок внутри которого много кружков?

Comment: https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/dyPmmvK

Comment: Создать много элементов с кружками?

Answer (score 2):

Сделать как предложили в комментариях

> Создать много элементов с кружками?

Не вариант, проще уже использовать изображение (растровое или векторное - ваш выбор).

Можно средствами CSS ([radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient())):

```css
.dots {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(
      circle,
      #f00 calc(35% - 1.25px),
      transparent 35%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```